# ID is not getting assigned in array properly

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays

In my `datatable` , I assign values to `array`. But in my code, the values are not getting assigned properly.

From my `datatable`, there are 2 rows in the table. but while assigning I get error as

> Index was outside the bounds of the array.

Here is my code

```
if (DtGrid.Rows[IntPriCount]["control_type"].ToString().ToUpper() == "T")
{
    //Array for storing the Control ID.
    string[] StrArrPriTextID = DtGrid.Rows[IntPriCount]["control_id"].ToString().Split(',');
    HidTextControl.Value += StrArrPriTextID[2].ToString() + ";"; //error line
    //Array for storing the Function name.
    string[] StrArrFun = DtGrid.Rows[IntPriCount]["fun_name"].ToString().Split(',');
    //HTML Table row object.
    HtmlTableRow ObjPriTr = new HtmlTableRow();
    //HTML table cell object.
    HtmlTableCell ObjPriTd = new HtmlTableCell();
    ObjPriTd.InnerText = DtGrid.Rows[IntPriCount]["label_name"].ToString();
    ObjPriTd.Attributes.Add("class", "label");
    ObjPriTr.Cells.Add(ObjPriTd);
}
```

Comment: you need to show what you have in the `"control_id"` which you are splitting but I assume you don't have an array with position 2: `StrArrPriTextID[2]`. Remember that when it comes to index values it starts from 0

Comment: @GiladGreen: in control_id, i have `Txt_SURVEY` id of the textbox. and there are two id's in all

Comment: can you show some data? In particular `DtGrid.Rows[IntPriCount]["control_id"].ToString().Split(',')`

Comment: if you only have two IDs, they are indexed as [0] and [1] - there would be no [2]

Comment: In `HidTextControl.Value += StrArrPriTextID[2].ToString() + ";";` The index value shall be [0] or [1] only. There is no index [2] available as there are only 2 records.

Comment: @GiladGreen: `DtGrid.Rows[IntPriCount]["control_id"].ToString().Split(',')` gives me data as `{string[1]}`

Comment: @ShannonHolsinger: It was written by default. I cant make any changes in this.

Comment: @ManishDalal: even if I add `StrArrPriTextID[1].ToString()` I get error as `Out of bound array index`

Comment: Can you not use `StrArrPriTextID[IntPriCount].ToString()`, as for the first time the index will be zero only. For more analysis, please share complete code of this function (or event handler method)

Comment: @ManishDalal: I tried with `IntPriCount` here what happens is when it loops for the **last** time, the debugger takes value as `StrArrPriTextID[IntPriCount].ToString() + ";` and gives error as **Newline in constant**

Comment: **Newline in constant** is a compile time error and not a runtime bug. What you are saying cannot happen. Kindly share complete function code so that I can assist.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122186/discussion-between-stack-and-manish-dalal).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It possible that you control_id column contains a value that does not have a comma (like a single control's ID).

In that case after `Split()` in below line

`string[] StrArrPriTextID = DtGrid.Rows[IntPriCount]["control_id"].ToString().Split(',');`

the array StrArrPriTextID will have only one element.

So, you should change the error line

`HidTextControl.Value += StrArrPriTextID[2].ToString() + ";";`

to

```
foreach(string str in StrArrPriTextID)
    HidTextControl.Value += str + ";";
```

Hope that helps.